# Почему pdo обрезает нули при UPDATE в таблицу?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, строки, pdo

Здравствуйте.

Суть проблемы.

Нужно дату преобразовать в число. Дата передается из javascript через ajax и уже на стороне сервера сформировывается нужное число. К недостающим числам дописывается нули (если необходимо), а так же к месяцу +1. В итоге образуется такая строка (именно строка, а не число), `'010220152309'`. И все это отправляется в базу. После обновления таблицы, в базе лежат такое число `2147483647`. При чем это всегда так, вне зависимости от измененной даты, которое обновляется в базе.

Структура таблицы, куда заносятся данные:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date_int` int(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

Сам запрос:

```
$sql_upd = $DBH->prepare('
    UPDATE              `test_table`
    SET                 `test_table`.`date_int`     = :date_int
    WHERE               `test_table`.`id`           = :id;
');
$sql_upd->bindParam(':date_int', $str               = $date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql_upd->bindParam(':id', $str                     = (int)$_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql_upd->execute();
```

P.S. Почему я усложняю задачу, вместо того, чтоб просто воспользоваться функцией date()? Нужно сохранить в базе локальное (то что на компе у юзера), а не серверное время и в виде одного числа.

Из-за чего урезаются нули, которые добавлены к строке? И как с этим бороться? И почему всегда одно и тоже число сохраняется в СУБД?

Comment: Число, в mysql как и принято в математике, само нулями не дополняется. Тип int - это вообще 4 байта и в них физически невозможно сохранить никакую информацию о ведущих нулях. Если надо получить число с ведущими нулями преобразуйте его в строку и дополняйте недостающими нулями слева `lpad(число,12,'0')`. Но Ипатьев в общем прав, дату стоит хранить как дату, а при выводе, если нужно ее видеть в определенном формате использовать date_format  http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html

Comment: Если вам вообще нужна строка, то почему вы ее записываете в число?

Comment: @PoyCc И да, 12 значное десятичное число в 4 байта int не влезают и mysql сохраняет максимально возможное для чисел типа int значение около 2 млрд.

Comment: @Mike благодарю за ответ, попробую воспользоваться вашим советом

Comment: @PoyCc В случае чего вы можете воспользоваться типом bigint он в 2 раза больше int ...

Comment: @Mike благодарю за ваш совет, по поводу смены типов с `int` на `bigint`. Работает как надо. Напишите отдельный ваш ответ, чтоб мне выбрать как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для хранения вы выбрали тип `int`, со знаком данный тип позволяет хранить максимальное число 2147483647. Дата в указанном вами формате превышает это число, поэтому MySQL просто ставит максимально возможное. Для хранения больших чисел можно использовать тип `bigint`, который позволяет хранить примерно 9 квинтиллионов (9x10^18).

Но это именно числа, поэтому при выводе из базы они будут без ведущих нулей. Что бы получить число с ведущими нулями надо преобразовать его в строку и самостоятельно дополнить нулями до нужной длины, например с помощью функции MySQL `lpad(число,12,'0')` (где 12 - количество разрядов до которых надо дополнять нулями). Так же, при сохранении числа в базе его дополнять нулями слева не имеет особого смысла, хранимое число от этого не изменится.

И да, дату лучше хранить в поле типа datetime, по крайней мере с ней легко будет проводить какие либо операции как с датой, прибавлять и вычитать дни, выводить функцией `date_format` в удобном пользователю формате. (Правда я так понял из комментариев, что конечная цель у вас совсем другая, так что вам решать)

Comment: Благодарю вас, за ваш ответ. Оказывается так все просто.

Answer (score 5):

1. PDO здесь абсолютно не при чем.
2. Для работы с БД надо знать, [какие значения можно записывать в выбранное поле](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).
3. При этом не надо удивляться странностям БД, записывая *строку (именно строку, а не число)* в поле, *численного* типа.
4. В любом случае, "К недостающим числам дописывается нули (если необходимо), а так же к месяцу +1. В итоге образуется такая строка" - это какой-то нереально адов костыль.
5. Дату и время в Mysql надо хранить в поле типа datetime и передавать в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС, **и не заниматься никакой самодеятельностью.**

Отдельно хочу отметить необъяснимую страсть пользователей пхп к рисованию. Код, занимающий ровно две строчки, они умудряются расписать на целую страницу.

```
$sql_upd = $DBH->prepare('UPDATE test_table SET date = ? WHERE id = ?');
$sql_upd->execute([$date,$_POST['id']]);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ, советы. Я бы и рад бы воспользоваться 5-м пунктом и забыть эту задачу как страшный сон. Но все же мне необходимо сохранить дату именно в виде числа, без дополнительных символов. И я вот понять не могу почему всегда одно и то же значение заносится в СУБД. Самое главное, что если изменить структуру таблицы с `int` на `varchar`, то эта проблема сама отпадает и данные в базу заносятся те что надо.

Comment: Нет, тебе это не нужно. Нужно слушать, что тебе говорят старшие, и если какие-то твои идем не соответствуют правильному подходу, то исправить эти идеи.

Comment: Там не все так просто, значения которые заносятся в базу в виде единого числа, выполняют несколько функций, которые не сочетаются с выводом привычным для СУБД даты.

Comment: Во-первых, сразу можно сказать, что функции эти дурацкие, и изобретены от неграмотности. Просто оттого, что ты не знаешь как правильно. Во-вторых, про *вывод* из базы данных тут речь вообще не шла. У тебя здесь вопрос про то , как вводить и хранить дату в базе данных. А на это вопрос ответ однозначный, я дал на него ответ выше.

Comment: Нет, речь же идет не про извлечение, а про занесение в базу нужного числа состоящего из даты. То что вы сказали, про занесение в базу нужной даты в правильном для базы формате, я в курсе про это. Просто для работы мне нужен именно формат в виде одного числа без доп. символов. Так как к дате будет заносится еще много чего другого, например таймзоны юзера, ip юзера, геолокация и все это будет в виде одного числа. Поэтому я сразу откинул вариант MySQL и PHP даты.

Comment: То есть, вариант записать ip и геолокацию в *отдельные поля таблицы* ты не рассматривал?

Comment: Это все нужно для формирования определенного ида, с зашифрованными данными, которые будут нести определенный смысл

Comment: Дешифровщик готов уже давно, просто не мог понять из-за чего это происходит, я про суть проблемы, описанную в описании к вопросу.

Comment: Если прям так необходимо писать дату в виде числа, может стоит использовать формат [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: @PoyCc если ты до сих пор не понял, то формировать свой никому не нужный "шифр" ты можешь как угодно,  но данные в базе надо хранить как положено.